# MySQL or PHP: Link two fields and then compare to fields populated at another time

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to MySQL and PHP. Usually I need a little bit of help with a language and then I can get going from there. So I would really appreciate the help with my first "complex" problem. I have the database below which holds data about a network and is populated every five minutes. The MAC address is the only really static value as it is attached to the hardware (make) so it can be used as a key. Everything else is subject to change. This is a truncated sample of my database. Sometimes there are more or less rows per time.

I have been working on a PHP front-end to display the data and one feature I would like to add is to compare the listed IPs, as well as MAC-IP pairs from the latest time to the previous time. And if an IP exists or does not exist in the current time compared to the previous time, get those rows. Also, if a MAC switched to a different IP or an IP switched to a different MAC, get those rows too.

Basically, these are some of the queries I am using to get the data for display in PHP but they are just very basic for just showing what is in the table. Thank you and I appreciate the help. Any answers will help me learn a lot and I should be able to figure out a lot more on my own after this. Thank you!

```
/* Get all results for Today's Date */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE date = '$DateToday' ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC") or die('Error with mysql_query');

$CurrentLogTime = $row['time']; // Variable set to time field of first row.

/* Get all results for Today's Date and most recent log time. */
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE date = '$DateToday' and time = '$CurrentLogTime'") or die('Error with result2');

/* Get all results for Today's Date and previous log time. */
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosts WHERE date = '$DateToday' and time = TIMEDIFF ('$CurrentLogTime', '00:05')") or die('Error with result3');
```

---

```
+------------+----------+----------------------+-------------------+------+------+----------------------+-------+------+--------+-------+------+
| date       | time     | ip                   | mac               | name | dns  | make                 | owner | note | status | specs | os   |
+------------+----------+----------------------+-------------------+------+------+----------------------+-------+------+--------+------+-------+
| 2012-08-22 | 00:00:00 | 192.168.30.1         | 00:00:00:00:00:00 | NULL | NULL | Supermicro Computer  | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 2012-08-22 | 00:00:00 | 192.168.30.10        | BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB | NULL | NULL | Generic Server       | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.1         | 11:11:11:11:11:11 | NULL | NULL | Supermicro Computer  | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.2         | 00:50:56:A4:52:5E | NULL | NULL | VMware               | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.3         | 00:0A:9C:52:88:8C | NULL | NULL | Server Technology    | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.10        | BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB | NULL | NULL | Generic Server       | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |
```

As an example to clarify what I am trying to do. I always want my HTML/PHP front end to display the rows from the latest date and time. If we use the example above, I want my user to see all rows for 00:05 when they browse to the webpage. That is easy enough. Now let's say at 00:00, I have the MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 paired up to 192.168.30.1. But then at 00:05 the MAC 11:11:11:11:11:11 has taken 192.168.30.1. I want to highlight that row in my HTML. Also, let's say that at 00:00 the only IPs at that time were 192.168.30.1 and 192.168.30.10. But then at 00:05, not only is there 192.168.30.1 and .10 but there is also 192.168.30.2 and 192.168.30.3. I want to highlight the rows of the new IPs that showed up at 00:05. Finally, we see the IP-MAC pair for 192.168.30.10 is the same between both times. I still want to echo this when I generate the end-users table, but I don't want to highlight it in any way. So the end result should be a webpage generated with something kinda like this, where IP-MAC combinations which changed from the previous time are bolded.

**| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.1         | 11:11:11:11:11:11 | NULL | NULL | Supermicro Computer  | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |**
**| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.2         | 00:50:56:A4:52:5E | NULL | NULL | VMware               | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |**
**| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.3         | 00:0A:9C:52:88:8C | NULL | NULL | Server Technology    | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |**
| 2012-08-22 | 00:05:00 | 192.168.30.10        | BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB | NULL | NULL | Generic Server       | NULL  | NULL | NULL   | NULL  | NULL |

And when it comes to determining the rows which have changed, I don't know if it is best to do with MySQL or just get the rows of the latest two updates and use PHP to figure out what has changed? Keep in mind, my actual database will have over 100 entries per time.

Logically, here is a little more detail on what I am trying to do. Basically, using the example above, I want to create two arrays for comparison. I've figured out how to CONCAT the two fields for comparison but don't really know where to go from there although I am still researching. This is pretty frustrating to me because I could easily get these results with shell scripting and input them straight into the database. I am trying to do as much in PHP and MySQL as possible but the thought of having my shell script figure this out is becoming more appetizing. But basically this is what I am trying to do with the table above but I don't even know whether it would be best to use MySQL or PHP for the operation. >.<

```
Array1
mac               | ip
00:00:00:00:00:00 | 192.168.30.1
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB | 192.168.30.10

Array2
mac               | ip
11:11:11:11:11:11 | 192.168.30.1
00:50:56:A4:52:5E | 192.168.30.2
00:0A:9C:52:88:8C | 192.168.30.3
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB | 192.168.30.10
```

WHERE Array1.ip == Array2.ip or Array1.mac == Array2.mac
do
CONCAT Array1.ip,Array1.mac = Compare1 and CONCAT Array2.ip,Array2.mac = Compare2
if Compare1 != Compare2
then
echo the row as bold

Comment: If you're new to MySQL and PHP then you shouldn't be using `mysql_query`. This is for legacy applications only. New applications should be using `mysqli` or PDO to avoid extremely serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) like you have in this example.

Comment: Thanks, I knew mysqli was the new and safer way to do things but started learning queries from an outdated O'Reilly book. I'll start using mysqli.

Comment: Those books came from a simpler, more idllic time. A happy place where tools [like this](http://sqlmap.org/) didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Using separate `date` and `time` fields is not going to help you that much. If anything you should have a single `datetime` unless you need to do reports by day, in which case `date` would be relevant for creating the appropriate index. As a note, try to avoid naming columns after internal SQL types. `date` could be `on_date` and `time` could be `at_time` just to eliminate confusion. As a plus these won't have to be escaped when used in queries.

Using an indexed `datetime` field called `created_At` allows you to `ORDER BY created_at DESC` which is probably what you want here when trying to figure out if a change has occurred.

You can also use the `BETWEEN` operator to select ranges of datetime values in order to check for changes over a particular interval.

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for so you might have to be more specific, or try and re-structure this so that the queries become more self-apparent.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a little more to think about. I updated my original question with an example at the bottom and reduced my example table to maybe make what I am trying to accomplish a bit more clear.